# Prevent people from seeing other user profile pictures

Tags: django, django-templates

I created a field to allow a user to upload a profile picture. In the template I check if the user is logged in and there is a profile image, otherwise I display a generic one. How can you prevent someone from guessing other filenames to see another users profile picture?

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.profile.image %}
<span class="avatar avatar-sm" style="background-image: url({{ user.profile.image.url }})"></span>
{% else %}
<span class="avatar avatar-sm" style="background-image: url('/media/profile_pics/default.png)')"></span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: To protect the user images you should add an authentication middleware to the `profile_pics` route

Answer (score 0):

##### Here I created a code snippet

##### Basically, I handled three cases

```
1 - Authorised User
2 - Unauthorised User
3 - Authorised User but not uploaded a profile pic
```

#### Html Code

```
{% block body %}
     <h3>User is Authenticated or Not = {{user.is_authenticated}}</h3>
     <hr>     
     
     {% for i in data %}
     <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 120px; width: 120px; text-align: center; "> 
          {% if user.is_authenticated and i.photo %}
          <div >
               <img height="80px" src="{{i.photo.url}}" alt="">
               
          </div>
          {% else %}
          <div >
               <img height="80px" src="{% static 'images/1.png' %}" alt="">
          </div>
          {% endif %}
          <p>User = {{forloop.counter}}</p>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock body %}
```

##### Case - 1 Output for Authorised User all images uploaded

[image]

##### Case - 2 Output for Unauthorised User serve  generic one from static

[image]

##### Case - 3 Output (here user is logged in but User-4 has not uploaded a profile pic so serve static image)

[image]

Comment: Is data the profile that I would provide in the view?